# default keyword in php

Tags: php, default

what does the keyword `default` in php do? there's no documentation on http://php.net/default, but i get an error when using it as a function name: »unexpected T_DEFAULT, expecting T_STRING«

what does it do/where can i find information about it?

Comment: omg, it's for the default case in `switch` … now i feel stupid :-/

Comment: case insensitivity strikes again, I wanted a DEFAULT constant in a class :D

Comment: Note that as of PHP7, it is possible to have the name "default" (as well as other) used for a few things, like a class' method since the lexer is smarter than before. See https://wiki.php.net/rfc/context_sensitive_lexer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`default` is part of the `switch` statement:

```
switch ($cond) {
  case 1:
    echo '$cond==1';
    break;
  case 2:
    echo '$cond==2';
    break;
  default:
    echo '$cond=="whatever"';
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The `default` keyword is used in the [`switch` construct](http://php.net/switch):

```
$value = 'A';
switch ($value) {
case 'A':
case 'B':
    echo '$value is either A or B.';
break;
case 'C':
    echo '$value is C.';
break;
default:
    echo '$value is neither A, nor B, nor C.';
}
```

The *default* case matches anything that wasn’t matched by the other cases.

Answer (score 5):

Adding to others answers:

`default` is a PHP keyword and keywords cannot be used as function name.

When you try:

```
function default () {
 ....
}
```

PHP expects to see a `T_STRING` ( an identifier) after the keyword `function` but sees a `T_DEFAULT` and flags a parse/syntax error:

> unexpected T_DEFAULT, expecting T_STRING